# PHP not working localhost

Tags: php, mysql, image, uploading

I'm working on a site here.  On a portion of the site the admin will be able to upload a picture and it will be stored on the server and also make an entry into the database with the location and when it was uploaded.

I am working locally but using WAMP as a test server.  If I manually run localhost/includes/db.php (database connection) in the address bar I can see it connected as I get "Connected successfully".

```
    <?php

try {

   $dbname = "woody_tools";
   $user = "site";
   $pass = "site";
   $host = "localhost";


   # MySQL with PDO_MYSQL
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }

catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

?>
```

This is the form control from the page I am using where the admin chooses and uploads the pic.

```
<form action="includes/saveimage.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

          <table style="border-collapse: collapse; font: 12px Tahoma;" border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5"> <!-- Table to upload products -->
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><input name="uploadedimage" type="file"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input name="Upload Now" type="submit" value="Upload Image"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          </table>  <!-- Table to upload products -->
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And the code for the php page that is supposed to handle uploading the image and updating the database.

```
<?php
include("includes/db.php");

    function GetImageExtension($imagetype)
     {
       if(empty($imagetype)) return false;
       switch($imagetype)
       {
           case 'image/bmp': return '.bmp';
           case 'image/gif': return '.gif';
           case 'image/jpeg': return '.jpg';
           case 'image/png': return '.png';
           default: return false;
       }
     }



if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"])) {

    $file_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"];
    $temp_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["tmp_name"];
    $imgtype=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["type"];
    $ext= GetImageExtension($imgtype);
    $imagename=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"];
    $target_path = "Product_Images/".$imagename;


if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path)) {

    $query_upload="INSERT into 'images_tbl' ('images_path','submission_date') VALUES 

('".$target_path."','".date("Y-m-d")."')";
    mysql_query($query_upload) or die("error in $query_upload == ----> ".mysql_error());  

}else{

   exit("Error While uploading image on the server");
} 

}

?>
```

When I run this code through I can choose a picture and hit "upload" but this is where things go wrong.  I get the following error.  Please point me in the right direction.

[image: Snippet of the error message]

I know the database connection uses PDO and the saveimages.php does not.  I borrowed this script from a tutorial found [here](http://www.onlinebuff.com/article_step-by-step-to-upload-an-image-and-store-in-database-using-php_40.html) .  Once I got it working I was going to try and translate it to PDO.  As I'm doing all this to teach myself I'm trying to take baby steps.  Also I confirmed no data has been added to the database after running these.

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Did you edit your php.ini? On what port are you running this localhost session?

Comment: Make sure the files exist. PHP says they don't.

Comment: I did not edit it no.  Its running on what ever the default is.  going to check now.

Comment: check your path: with `echo getcwd()` you can print your working directory, maybe you are not where you think you are - so you can check yur path to your include

Comment: show me you directory and files structure

Comment: Yes I just looked and the files are saved in the includes/ directory

Comment: try `require_once` instead of `include`, and right before your db.php path, insert `__DIR__` constant to make it a full path. Your php.ini is configured to search for root path of projects in C:\php\pear when `include` is used.

Comment: Thanks Aedix Rhinedale  I changed to require_once and ran everything.  Now I get only this error:     Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION) in C:\wamp\www\woody\includes\saveimage.php on line 4

Comment: You probably missed a semicolon after `require_once`.

Comment: `require_once(__DIR__."/db.php");` see if it fits.

Comment: That worked except now I have a syntax error In the sql apparently.  Time to start looking at the PDO version of this.  Thanks @Aedix Rhinedale you were dead right

Answer (score 0):

Directory structure snippet of sublime:

[image]

Comment: There is no need to make an answer to complete your question. Edit it and insert new information.

Comment: I thought of that as I submitted it...Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `include("db.php");` instead of `include("includes/db.php");` because the `saveimage.php` is located in `includes` directory.

You also have to make sure that the `Product_Images` directory is located in the `includes` directory and your webserver has the permission to write into that directory.

Comment: I've done and I am still getting this error now.                         Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION) in C:\wamp\www\woody\includes\saveimage.php on line 4
           I am assuming that PHP doesn't like the "GetImageExtension($imagetype)"..  I did some searching and old versions 5.3 and below had this issue I'm running 5.5.12

Comment: Please show me the first 5 lines of your `saveimage.php`. I think there is a missing brace of something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone.  @Aedix Rhinedale had it right on.  I forgot the ;.  Also he gave me some great alternatives!!!